# jQuery load and callback not functioning

Tags: jquery, ajax, onload

I have a design powered by an ajax script. The script allows for callbacks for certain pages where needed. The design is a simple grid of thumbnails, click a thumbnail and the new page slides in displaying larger images. I am trying to have some kind of preloader for the larger images, which will fade in the images sequentially when they have loaded. My script to initialise the ajax and the callback looks like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#menu ul li").slidingPage({
        easing: 'easeInOutExpo',
        speed: 1100,
        slideScroll: 'horizontal',
        top: 0,
        navigation: {
                show: false,
                nestedPagesFlows: true
        },
        callbacks: {

                loader: function () {

                    $(function () {
                        $(".fadein").fadeIn("slow");
                    });

                    $(window).load(function () {
                        $(".preload").each(function (i) {
                            $(this).delay(400 * i).fadeIn();
                        });
                    });

                }
        }
    });
})
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="fadein">
<div id="images">

<h1>Title</h1>

<div class="centre">    

<img alt="#" class="preload" src="...">
<img alt="#" class="preload" src="...">

</div>

</div>
</div>
```

The `fadein` function works as expected but the `preload` does not. Preloaded images are hidden with the CSS, but they never appear, the callback is only invoked after the page is refreshed, not on load, which I guess is the problem here. To be honest I have no idea why or even if what I am doing is somehow not compatible. Any advice on how I can fix this, or some suggestions for an alternative way, maybe hiding the images with jQuery? Thanks

Comment: Are we to assume this behaves the same in all browsers?

Comment: Yep it's all browsers, same behaviour

Comment: Where is the code that uses `yourobject.callbacks.loader`?

Comment: I tried that originally, for some reason the $(window).load does not fire at all in the ajaxed page. I also experimented with preloading all images on initial site load, but it takes too long... the only way I have got it to work is by using CSS3

Comment: Try putting _everything_ inside a `window.load` which will prevent any code execution until the page (and all its assets incl. images are fully loaded).  Remove the `window.load` that's inside your `loader:` handler.  I've also noticed that IE does not do a good job firing `window.load` when images are hidden... it's like they're ignored, never loaded, and `window.load` is fired anyway.

Comment: removing the window.load lets the images load normally, I'm not sure what you mean by put everything inside a window.load, if I do that it breaks the ajax script

Comment: @Sparky672 I have solved this, thanks for your suggestions. I will be sure to post the solution when I am permitted :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using jQuery's `.load()` API instead of `window.load`. Example:

```
$('#selector').load(function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

Not sure if it's the most efficient way, but it achieves the desire effect.